# Which join type is used when using just JOIN in PostgreSql?

Tags: postgresql, join, self-join

I prefer to indicate join types when I use it in database systems but when I switch to a new project, there is a single `join` is used. Generally I prefer to use `LEFT JOIN` or `INNER JOIN` according to my needs, but I have not found which JOIN type is considered when a single `JOIN` is used in `PostgreSQL`.

```
select p.uuid from Product s " +
       join Category c on p.uuid = c.siteUuid
       join Brand b on b.uuid = c.brandUuid
```

Comment: Just JOIN is INNER join.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inner Join is the default join when we use plain `JOIN`.

For better readablity of the queries, It is always preferred to write `INNER JOIN`

Reference:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.4.3.1.2

Comment: "*For better readablity*" is arguably very much personal taste. I find it _harder_ to read when unnecessary noise words are used.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it is not related to readability I think. Because there are lots of cases that we need to use LEFT JOIN when we need to keep all the records from the first table before JOIN. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Henry How can the choice of using a term not be entirely about readability? You are asking what a naked JOIN means; now that you know what it means you can use it to mean that & not anything else. PS How is your "because" sentence a justification for the sentence it precedes?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and @Henry Yes it is `personal taste `  :) but IMHO for someone who know about inner join well but doesn't know by default join keyword is inner join, Writing inner join will help in that case.

Comment: If you advocate to always use `inner join` you will also have to always use `left outer join` rather than just `left join`

Comment: @no_name_horse do you mean that left and inner join can be used for each other?